# Compare two KeyValue types data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below data available in a table

```
DECLARE @AddressTbl As Table (ID int identity,Address varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @AddressTbl
VALUES ('State:AndhraPradesh,Dist:Prakasam')
```

Next time when I enter the same value I should be notified that this value exists in the table.

For this I will use an sp with warning message that the data is available. But I want how to implement the logic to compare the data.

```
Create Procedure usp_InsertAddress
(
@Address varchar(100)
)
AS
DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID=(SELECT ID FROM @AddressTbl WHERE Address = @Address)
IF @ID IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @AddressTbl
    VALUES ('State:AndhraPradesh,Dist:Prakasam')
END;
```

I may enter the address like `'Dist:Prakasam,State:AndhraPradesh'` 
and there may be some blank spaces also. So need to parse the address and check the key and values.

- I will use permanent table instead of table variable.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: This design is violating the most important rules of normalisation. You should never ever store one than more piece of information in one cell. Futhermore, using a stored procedure to check the input is the wrong place. You might use a trigger, but - as said above - you should rework the whole approach. This will be just headaches...

Answer (score 0):

You can use if exists for check. Or you can add unique CONSTRAINT in your table. The UNIQUE constraint ensures that all values in a column are different. This will return error if you are trying to insert duplicate value.

```
Create Procedure usp_InsertAddress
(
  @Address varchar(100)
)
AS
  if exists(SELECT ID FROM @AddressTbl WHERE Address = @Address)
  begin
    select 'Value is Already Exist in Table'---For Warning
  end
  else
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @AddressTbl
    VALUES ('State:AndhraPradesh,Dist:Prakasam')
    select 'Value Inserted Sucessful'---For Success
  END;
```

Comment: The value I entered mayn't be the same format.
I may Enter like ('Dist:Prakasam,State:AndhraPradesh') then the condition may produce the wrong result.
And there may be some blank spaces also. So I need to parse it and check the key and values.

Comment: @sasibhushan in that case you need to expand your question and clarify exactly what data formats might come in, and how they should be compared. i.e. we need sample data that covers all use cases. Really though you should consider storing your data *properly* as this is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: @sasibhushan and you need to do some research on string splitting functions yourself, there are lots and lots of question and answers out there on this subject, because people continue to make this design mistake and then have to solve the problems that come with it. You can't expect someone to just write it for you. Do the research, have a go and post a question when stuck.